# Load security class with custom classloader

Tags: java, security, classloader, javassist

We are creating a javassist based custom class-loader modifying some classes byte code on loading. Part of the project is also a signed jar containing a security provider.

The initialization of the Loader simply looks like follows:

```
private final Loader initLoader(ClassLoader master) {
    final ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    final Loader loader = new Loader(master, pool);
    try {
        loader.addTranslator(pool, new MyTranslator());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return loader;
}
```

The `MyTranslator` class does the modifications but does not care about the security relevant classes. The `master` is the system (parent) class loader.

When the application comes to the part when loading the relevant security classes this exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider EXAMPLE-PROV
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:100) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:230) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at my.example.app.security.ExampleKeyAgreement.generateSharedSecret(ExampleKeyAgreement.java:56) ~[?:?]
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: Class is on the bootclasspath
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:159) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:185) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:97) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:230) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at my.example.app.security.ExampleKeyAgreement.generateSharedSecret(ExampleKeyAgreement.java:56) ~[?:?]
```

My question is, if there is a way to load these classes from a custom class-loader without violating the java security mechanisms?

The method `javassist.Loader#setDomain(ProtectionDomain)` says

*Without registering an appropriate protection domain, the program loaded by this loader will not work with a security manager or a signed jar file.*

How can I create or determine a valid `ProtectionDomain` instance?